# Atom hides my files and folders when the the tree view is open. How to show them again?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm not sure how i got this behavior. When i start atom **for a split second** my tree view looks normal - every file and folder of the project is shown - but ***then it collapses upwards*** and i can't bring it back.

I'm on windows 10. This is not the `Ctrl + \` or `Ctrl + b` - toggle tree problem. My Tree View is toggled open as you can see below. But the files are hidden. I'm not sure what to do.

[image]

**Is this a bug, or there is a key combination for this?**

Note: i'm not sure - but this could be a bug because this behavior is not particularly useful. Why anyone would want to take up 25% of the screen if nothing useful is shown? The `Toggle Tree View` behavior that Atom exposes by default - with the `Ctrl + \` key-combination - makes much more sense to me..

Answer (score 0):

Solve it! This happen after the recent update of [project-dropdown package](https://atom.io/packages/project-dropdown). I disabled this plugin and now everything is fine.